# Grouped headings in formattable

Tags: r, r-markdown

So I'm trying to create a table like this

[image]

However, I can't seem to find a way to add the second grouping header (Apple, Orange, Grapes).

Is there a way to do this in the formattable package?

Comment: Are you open to other packages? This is possible with `tab_spanner` in [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html).

Comment: Unfortunately it does look like I have to use another package entirely.